# Configure QGIS in a project on PyCharm on Ubuntu

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, pyside

I'm creating a PySide2 project and i'd like to know if it's possible to add QGIS in it.
When i puted "from qgis" it does not work.

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from qgis._core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayer
```